# React-Navigation added to existing apps

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

Some background for context...I'm creating a `react-native` app that will live in it's own repository. This app will be integrated into other web, iOS, and Android apps. I'm currently working with the Android app. This is an existing native app written in Java.

I've "wrapped" it with a super basic React Native app, following the [React Native Docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-existing-apps). For testing purposes, to mimic what will end up being the production app, I have a **native** activity, `MainActivity` in the Android app, with a button that opens the second activity, `ReactNativeActivity` which is loads my React Native app. This is working - the React Native app loads. The React Native App has a button that should navigate to a second screen within the React Native app (using `react-navigation`). When I press that button, instead of navigating to the next screen in my stack, it instead reloads `MainActivity` from the native Android app. Running the same thing on web there is no issue with navigation, so I know the screens are hooked up right. I'm not new to React Native, but I am new to integrating with existing Native applications.

**Edited to add some code as requested**

The Navigator and the button are as follows:

```
// navigator.tsx
import React from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";

import { HomeScreen } from "../screens/Home";
import Demo from "../screens/Demo";

export type NavigationStackParamList = {
  HomeScreen: undefined;
  Demo: undefined;
};

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<NavigationStackParamList>();

export const Navigation = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen component={Demo} name="Demo" />
        <Stack.Screen
          component={HomeScreen}
          name="HomeScreen"
          options={{ title: "Home" }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

// Demo Screen
const Demo: React.FC<DemoScreenProps> = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.app}>
      <View style={styles.info}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Demo</Text>
        <Text>Running on: </Text>
        <Text style={styles.platform}>{Platform.OS}</Text>
      </View>
      <Map />
      <Button
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("HomeScreen")}
        title="Go to Test Screen"
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Pressing "Go to Test Screen" above, is what is causing the `MainActivity` to reload, rather than the correct screen.

Comment: could you show your code  where you configure the navigator and the  button function?

Comment: I've updated to add some sample code. Thanks @JavierAlejandro.

Comment: look this : 
import { HomeScreen } from "../screens/Home";
import Demo from "../screens/Demo";